# How to prevent screen readers from reading out status bar notifications when updated

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications, screen-readers

My app updates an *ongoing* notification on the Android status bar every second, to indicate the duration of the operation it has been working.

The problem is reported by a user using a screen reader software (for visually impaired users) that the content of notification is always read back every second.

Is there any way for us to indicate status bar notification updates not to be read by screen readers?

Comment: Do you set [Notification.Builder#setOnlyAlertOnce()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setOnlyAlertOnce%28boolean%29)? Not sure if that scenario was ever considered with Notifications so you may need to put an option in your app that prevents it from doing the update. Or try updating a [custom notification](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#CustomExpandedView) instead of updating the title or the message (whatever is read by the screenreader) since the screenreader should have no way to know how to read that.